# GWT error loading modules after upgrade from 1.7 to 2.0

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

in my project i've used gwt 1.7 but recently i've upgraded to 2.0. Now I have this error:

```
    ERROR: Unable to find 'portal.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
    ERROR: Failed to load module 'portal' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0' at localhost:40456
```

Portal - is a name of the module to load. I really don't have this file, instead I have Application.gwt.xml which contains this:

```
<module rename-to="portal">

    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <inherits name='com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT'/>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.http.HTTP'/>

    <source path="client"/>
    <source path="data"/>
    <source path="com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel"/>
    <source path="com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream"/>

    <!-- Inherit AMPS Applica module. -->
    <inherits name="com.example.core.application.AmpsApplicationApi"/>
    <inherits name="com.example.core.domain.CoreDomainApi"/>

    <!--  inherit css based theme -->

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
    <entry-point class='com.example.portal.ui.client.Application'/>

    <!-- Specify the application specific style sheet.              -->
    <stylesheet src='Application.css'/>
    <!--<stylesheet src='loginPage.css'/>-->

</module>
```

It seemed to work before, but now it doesn't.

P.S. I'm using Intellij Idea 12

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is when developing (i.e. not at compile-time); and I'd bet you're still using the HostedMode rather than the DevMode (or something like that).

As a side note, HostedMode will be removed starting with GWT 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove all the debug and run configurations before updated the clsspath ..

create a new configuration and try to run .